Games feel "laggy"
newbie here on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. 
This is my first serious try of getting used to Linux and so far I really like it.
The only issue I run into right now is, that every game feels kind of "unsmooth" or "laggy". When I turn on VSync it feels a little more smooth but then I have the high input delay, which is why I chose to deactivate it all the time. But even VSync doesn't quite feel the way it is supposed to be.
I have an Ryzen 5700X and RTX 2080 (non-oc) and all games I now tested were running fine on Windows. I tested CS2 and Minecraft (and other random indie games but they were fine. Minecraft and CS2 gave me the most visible difference between Windows and Linux) - which both have around 300+ FPS - but still these games feel like they're not smooth. My refresh rate is on 144hz because that's what my monitor has, but I feel like my games don't match the fps or refresh rate. I read other users have similar problems, that the refresh rate doesn't feel like the amount it is set to but rather just half of it.
I've read that disabling compositing is a way to fix it, but I am not sure if this is something I can do on Ubuntu, since it seems to be depending on what distribution you use. I really am new to this but want to stay, so I'd be thankful for any advice. Maybe there is some simple solution that I don't see yet.

Well, disabling "Force Full Composition Pipeline" and also "Force Composition Pipeline" fixed everything. I tried searching for that everywhere but didn't know its unter Display Configurations in nvidia-settings.

It seems that you have a discrete NVIDIA graphics card on your computer. Do you forget to install the NVIDIA driver for your Ubuntu system ?
To install NVIDIA driver:

Make sure you have disabled nouveau driver first. Type this command to check:
lsmod | grep nouveau

If there's nothing in the output, that means the nouveau driver has been successfully disabled, go to 2.
If there's something in the output, you should disable the nouveau driver.
Open file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf,
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Append these two lines to the file:
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0

Save the file and type commands below:
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot

After rebooting the computer, check again and make sure that nouveau driver is disabled.

Download NVIDIA driver matching your graphics card from https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx, it should be a *.run file.
Switch to tty mode first.
Stop the display server using:
sudo service gdm3 stop

Run the NVIDIA driver installer file:
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xxx.xx.run
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.xxx.xx.run

You will encounter some questions during the installation process:
1.The distribution-provided pre-install script failed! Are you sure you want to continue?
Choose continue installation.

2.Would you like to register the kernel module souces with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later?  
Choose No and continue.

3.Nvidia's 32-bit compatibility libraries....(I forget)
Choose No and continue.

4.Would you like to run the nvidia-xconfigutility to automatically update your x configuration so that the NVIDIA x driver will be used when you restart x? Any pre-existing x confile will be backed up.  
Choose Yes and continue.

After installation succeeds, restart the display server:
sudo service gdm3 start


Check installation:
Type the command to check:
nvidia-smi

If the output is something like this, that means your NVIDIA driver has been successfully installed.
Thu Apr  4 11:08:38 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.154.05             Driver Version: 535.154.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 ...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P8               6W /  40W |    706MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1129      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          317MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1819      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                           111MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1881      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                         35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4828      G   ...seed-version=20240403-050113.230000       43MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7620      G   ...sion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess       82MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8038      G   /usr/bin/systemsettings                      48MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10207      G   ...guageDetectionEnabled,Vulkan,WebOTP       39MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

(I use KDE instead of GNOME, don't mind it)

Launch your game, check if it's lagging anymore.
Hope the answer can help you.   :)


